# Save image in local storage captured with cordova media capture plugin

Tags: cordova, media, video-capture

I have added code in my ionic application using typescript to capture image. I have used cordova-media-capture plugin.

I am able to capture image, but when I go into my gallery I am not able to see that captured image.

I am having android Moto G4 mobile. Can anyone guide me on what could be the issue. Is it saving somewhere else or is I need to save it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

U can look into the array of `MediaFile` object in `OnSuccess()` function, describing each captured Image.

The `MediaFile` object has following properties -

> - **name**: The name of the file, without path information. (DOMString)
> - **fullPath**: The full path of the file, including the name. (DOMString)
> - **type**: The file's mime type (DOMString)
> - **lastModifiedDate**: The date and time when the file was last modified. (Date)
> - **size**: The size of the file, in bytes. (Number)

`fullPath` attribute will have the information you want.

Since you did not provide your code, I suppose your code is similar to this -

```
function imageCapture() {
   var options = {
      limit: 1
   };

   navigator.device.capture.captureImage(onSuccess, onError, options);

   function onSuccess(mediaFiles) {
      var i, path, len;

      for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
         path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;

         console.log(mediaFiles); 
         //u can see the log message for details of the captured file

         navigator.notification.alert(mediaFiles); //alert the details
      }
   }

   function onError(error) {
      navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
   }    
}
```

Refer the [Media Capture Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/index.html#capturecaptureimage) for more details.

Also see [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_media_capture.htm) (if required) for a working example.

Comment: I am using ionic 2, angular 2 with typescript
captureImage() {
        let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 1 };

        this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
            .then(
            (data: MediaFile[]) => {
                console.log(data);
                data.forEach(image => {
                    
                });
            }, (error: CaptureError) => console.error(error));
    }

This method is called on a button. But not sure whether it is saved in local or I have to save it. I am  not able to see that captured image in my gallery.

Comment: As said in the answer, try to explore more in that `MediaFile[]` object. Also ensure that all the required permissions are granted for the app. Ionic 2 and Angular 2 are just different frameworks. Idea will still be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked the fullPath and found the same in my device and I could see the images were saved. 

Thanks again. It really helped..:)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to play back an audio from our application, which is recorded using 3rd party recorder.
I have a button to record audio. The audio is recorded using media caputure captureAudio method. On capture it records audio and saves in local. How to get that and play it.

Comment: Kindly mark it as answer(green tick) to your question if my answer helped u. It will help others having same issue. For playing audio u can post another question as it's a different topic (not related to this question).